# How to add .exp file in QT project?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I am beginner in QT. I want to know is there is any way to add .exp file in QT project, or is there any work around to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure what is the .exp file but [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) allow you storing files with any extension in the application's executable.

I hope it help.

Comment: exp is export file